# Cant view a parsed m4v link in MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, itunes, nsxmlparser

I am parsing this xml file here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toptvepisodes/limit=10/xml.

I am getting the preview link from the xml file, but for some reason the url wont play in my MPMovieViewController. An example preview link would be this: http://a989.v.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/032/Video/26/5c/7d/mzm.aezfptde..640x480.h264lc.d2.p.m4v.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me why this will not play in my MPMovieViewController.

ps. Here is my code:

```
if (section == 2) {
    if (row == 0) {
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:previewlink]];
        NSLog(@"%@", previewlink);
        [self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue, apparently Apple's doesn't allow to show protected videos from iTunes from the SDK. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724052/playing-m4v-protected-content-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-or-avplayer-ios/5875309#5875309)